# Check if mail is sent with TIdSmtpRelay and handle error if not

Tags: email, delphi, smtp, indy

I'm trying to send mail with the `TIdSMTPRelay` component of `Indy` and this is the procedure I use :

```
procedure tryRelayTask;
var
  relayMsg : TIdMessage;
  LRelayRecipients: TIdEMailAddressList;
  LRelay : TIdSmtpRelay;
  SSLHandler : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  relayMsg := TIdMessage.Create;
  relayMsg.LoadFromFile(mailFileName);
  try
    LRelayRecipients := TIdEMailAddressList.Create(nil);
    try
      LRelayRecipients.Add.Address := recipientEmailAddress;
      LRelay := TIdSMTPRelay.Create(nil);
      try
        SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
        try
          SSLHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := myKeyFile;
          SSLHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := myCertFile;
          SSLHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := myRootCertFile;
          LRelay.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
          LRelay.SSLOptions.SSLSupport := SupportSSL;
          LRelay.DNSServer := myRelayDNSServer;            
          LRelay.Send(relayMsg, LRelayRecipients) ;
          if Lrelay.StatusList.Items[0].Sent then begin
            // message is sent ok ?
          end
          else begin
            // message is not sent ok - handleError
            handleRelayError(LRelay.StatusList.Items[0].ExceptionMessage);
          end;
        finally
          SSLHandler.Free;
        end;
      finally
        LRelay.Free;
      end;
    finally
      LRelayRecipients.Free;
    end;
  finally
    relayMsg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Sometimes the property `Lrelay.StatusList.Items[0].Sent` is `False` but the message is actually sent and therefore if I try to send it again I will end up sending it successfully `N` times instead of only 1. Can someone help me to send messages correctly with the `TIdSMTPRealy` component ?

Comment: What is the actual value of `ExceptionMessage` when `Sent` is false?

Comment: The value of ``ExceptionMessages`` looked like this : **Can not connect to MX servers for address xyz@xyz.com**

Comment: That particular error means `TIdSMTPRelay` was able to query DNS for the MX record (SMTP server IPs) of the `xyz.com` domain but was not able to connect to any of the reported servers, or negotiate a SSL/TLS session with any of them.  If `TIdSMTPRelay` were able to connect to a server, but not send the email to it, you would get a different error message.  Also, I just discovered that it is possible for `TIdSMTPRelay` to create multiple status items for a single address, so make sure you take that into account as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `TIdSMTPRelayStatusItem.Sent` property tells you whether the email was accepted by the SMTP server of the recipient specified in the `TIdSMTPRelayStatusItem.EmailAddress` property.  That does not tell you whether or not the email was actually delivered to the recipient itself.  The SMTP protocol does not provide that information to senders.  An SMTP server may accept an email for a recipient that it has to then forward/relay to another SMTP server in the background.  The only way to know if the email was delivered to the recipient is if the recipient itself sends an acknowledgement email back to the sender's mailbox.

If the `TIdSMTPRelayStatusItem.Sent` property is False, it means that an exception was raised during delivery to the recipient's SMTP server.  The `Message` of the exception is available in the `TIdSMTPRelayStatusItem.ExceptionMessage` property.  If the exception was raised due to an error message sent by the SMTP server, the `TIdSMTPRelayStatusItem.ReplyCode` and `TIdSMTPRelayStatusItem.EnhancedCode` properties are also populated.  Either way, you will also get an `TIdSMTPRelay.OnDirectSMTPStatus` event with its `Action` parameter set to `dmWorkEndWithException` instead of `dmWorkEndOK`.

So, the only way the email could have been delivered to a given recipient but its `Sent` value is False is if either:

1. the SMTP server accepted the email but sent an error reply back to `TIdSMPTRelay`
2. an uncaught exception was raised after delivery was successful but before a `Sent=True` status item could be created/populated.